# Codeigniter-for my project index.php in url was removed but after LAMP reinstallation same project without index.php in url not working(Ubuntu)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

My codeigniter project was running successfully without index.php in url. It all started after I upgraded to php 5.6 from 5.4 . During upgradation I have faced several issues regarding apache which I resolved successfully one by one due to which my project is successfully running now but all its asking is index.php in url.

My attempts:

1.I have checked the mod rewrite and enabled it

2.not changed .htaccess content in my project root as it already contains the code to bypass index.php from url

3.I have tried to replace the blank file httpd.conf with

```
<Directory /var/www>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory><Directory>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

4.$config['index_page'] = ''

5.In /etc/apache2/sites_available/default I have

```
 <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
```

Please help me!

Comment: Please check line 38 on `application/config/config.php`. If it is `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';` please change it to `$config['index_page'] = '';`

Comment: @DenizB. it was already $config['index_page'] = ' '; Didn't worked

Comment: I have also changed $config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO'; to $config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI'; in config.php but did't work.

Answer (score 1):

> > > **May be `rewrite` mod is not enabled**

Execute this in terminal

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: rewrite mode was enabled.However I executed the above commands. Didn't worked.

Comment: As per the above solution I used
sudo a2enmod rewrite
o/p : Module rewrite already enabled

 I went to etc/apache2/sites-available/default found this 
<Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
As per that solution there is no where 'AllowOverride None'

Comment: After trying many things I succeeded.And the following small change has worked for me
In /etc/apache2/apache2.conf,I have changed one line initially it was   AllowOverride None which I changed to  AllowOverride All
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>